# vertical mouse with configurable buttons

Tags: mice

I am looking for an ergonomic mouse with more buttons than two, but I want to be able to change one of them to do double-click.

It seems like the cheap vendors don't have any drivers to provide such functionality, but it's not easy to figure out by reading the specs.

Comment: Is price or another other factor a consideration that would help limit or guide a recommendation? (Edit the question if so)

Comment: You can use [software to make *any* mouse do that](https://superuser.com/a/442194/899186), don't worry about the "driver". Just worry about the ergonomics of the mouse and whether it has extra buttons at all.

Comment: Jeff this X-Mouse Button Control looks perfect! Write your comment as an answer and I will accept it